# Initialize linked list or work queue at compile time VS runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When writing Linux driver, we can choose to initialize linked list and work queue at compile time or runtime. What are the pros/cons of each of them? What are the consideration to choose between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a reinitialization subfunction (which, for example, might be called by `open()` or `ioctl()` operations), then the code to initialize the list at runtime has to be there.  If there is code to do it, subtle bugs might appear if the static initialization does not match what the runtime code does.

Runtime optimization tends to have little weight in device driver initialization.

If the list requires much memory, dynamic allocation is typical and that cannot be done from static initialization.